# Model artifact must be in the same region as your model error gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

i want to deploy my model(tensorflow) in vertex ai,GCP. steps that I've taken are such :

1. Create a new bucket in google cloud storage with region `asia-southeast1(singapore)`.
2. In that bucket, I've uploaded my tensorflow model folder (pb extension).
3. I tried to import my tensorflow model in vertex ai with region `asia-southeast1(singapore)`.
4. for the model artifact location, I've inputted the correct path. However I got the following error :

```
Model artifact must be in the same region as your model (asia-southeast1).
```

am i missing something here? If you need additional information, feel free to comment below

[screenshot of my vertexai gcp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leGa8.png)
[screenshot of my google cloud storage bucket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLk81.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I removed prevent public access retention on cloud storage bucket and it helped.